# How can I add to a data array from multiple files?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I've got a folder structure that looks like this:

```
.
├── Gruntfile.js
└── src
    └── assets
        └── blocks
          └── content.js
          └── buttons
              └── buttons1.js
              └── buttons2.js
          └── images
              └── images.js
```

Within my `content.js` file there is an empty array:

```
var data = {
    'snippets': []
};
```

And within each of the files i.e `buttons1.js` `buttons2.js` and `images.js` there is an array, example:

```
var snippet = [
    {
        'thumbnail': 'preview/button-01.png',
        'category': '119',
        'html':
            '<div>' +
            '<a href="#" class="is-btn is-btn-ghost2 is-upper">Read More</a> &nbsp;' +
            '\n<a href="#" class="is-btn is-btn-ghost1 is-upper">Buy Now</a>' +
            '</div>'
    }
]
```

Is there a way with Grunt (or any other process runner) to loop through all the .js files within the folder and read the value of the snippet array and then add it to the snippets in the `content.js` file?

So I'd end up with an array that looks like this (plus any other from the other files appended)

```
var data = {
    'snippets': [
 {
        'thumbnail': 'preview/button-01.png',
        'category': '119',
        'html':
            '<div>' +
            '<a href="#" class="is-btn is-btn-ghost2 is-upper">Read More</a> &nbsp;' +
            '\n<a href="#" class="is-btn is-btn-ghost1 is-upper">Buy Now</a>' +
            '</div>'
    }

]
};
```

I tried out the `grunt-contrib-concat` with the following configuration which simply creates a file with multiple snippet variables, not sure if there is a way to amend how it concats? Or if there is a different plugin available

```
    concat: {
      options: {
        separator: ';',
      },
      dist: {
        src: 'src/assets/blocks/*/*.js',
        dest: 'src/assets/blocks/content.js',
      },
    },
```

Comment: An approach might be to move each `snippets` array to its own JSON file (e.g. `buttons1.snippets.json`).  Then, within a simple Grunt task you could just `require` each JSON file; from each JS file (e.g. `buttons1.js`) you could `fetch` the associated JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom task for Grunt which does what I want it to

```
    merge_blocks: {
      build: {
        src: 'src/assets/blocks/*/*.js',
        dest: 'src/assets/blocks/content.js'
      }
    }


  grunt.registerMultiTask('merge_blocks', 'Merge blocks', function () {
    const fs = require('fs');
    grunt.log.write('[Block Merge] Loaded dependencies...').ok();

    // This is the main array
    var data_basic = {
      'snippets': []
    };

    this.files.forEach(function (file) {
      grunt.log.writeln('Processing ' + file.src.length + ' files.');

      //file.src is the list of all matching file names.
      file.src.forEach(function (f) {
        var data = require('./' + f);
        data_basic.snippets.push(...data);
        data = null;
      });

      grunt.log.writeln('Now saving file:' + file.dest);
      fs.appendFileSync(file.dest, 'var data_basic = ' + JSON.stringify(data_basic, null, '  '));

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML (add paths):

```
<script src="content.js"></script>  // we get data == { 'snippets': [] }

<script src="buttons1.js"></script> // we get snippet == [...]
<script>data.snippets.push(snippet);</script>

<script src="buttons2.js"></script> // we get snippet == [...]
<script>data.snippets.push(snippet);</script>

<script src="buttons3.js"></script> // we get snippet == [...]
<script>data.snippets.push(snippet);</script>

// we have each snippet in snippets
```

Basically, we load the container (`data`), then we load the `buttons` one by one, adding their `snippet` to `data`'s `snippets`.

Addendum: How about dynamically adding scripts?

```
dataScript=document.body.createElement("script");
dataScript.src="content.js";
document.body.append(dataScript);

buttonSrcs=["buttons1.js", "buttons2.js", "buttons3.js"]; // etc...
for(buttonSrc of buttonSrcs) {
  buttonScript=document.body.createElement("script");
  buttonScript.src=buttonSrc;
  document.body.append(buttonScript);
  data.snippets.push(snippet);
};
```

I've typed from memory and I hope I got the spellings right...

Comment: I have quite a large number of individual snippet files, don't want to be requiring each one and then pushing to the array within the browser, looking for a way to do it a build time to go through all the individual files and add to the main array in ```content.js``` so i only have to require that single file in the browser